# iframe url content should aplly css styles using jquery

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to change the iframe url css styles

```
<iframe id="anil" width="400" height="480" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/starter-template/"></iframe>
```

Tried it using jquery but couldn't solve it

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").css("background-color","yellow");
```

Comment: You can't do this if the page loaded into the frame is on a different domain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Unless you own `getbootstrap.com` there's no chance of that happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access by javascript the content of an iframe for security reasons.